# Two view controllers and avoiding spaghetti

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got 2 view controllers, and the second view controller needs to change a label in the first view controller. One way this can be done is to make the first view controller a property so the second view controller can change it directly.

Only problem is that it's spaghetti programming ... how would one achieve this without falling for this trap?

One idea I had was to use delegate protocol to do this. Curious of opinions if any other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple application that does small tasks like changing a label, it isn't highly frowned upon to create a property for the view controller. As your application grows, or if you need to do a lot of label changing, it may be best to set up delegates and protocols to change them for you. It's mainly up to you: if you have a team or a large/growing app, you might want to consider using delegates and protocols because odds are you'll be using them anyway for good MVC and KVO practices.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because I'm a relative Objective C noob (though by no means new to coding), but the delegation scheme almost *always* seems to result in some manner of elongated pasta to me -- except for the built-in systems such as the UITableViewController.

I recently need to create a system to update labels on custom tableview cells and found that it was far simpler and more understandable to use NSNotification.  In the controller where the new values come into being, we post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"UpdatedDatesNotification" object: formattedDates];
```

... and in the subclass that creates the UITableViewCell containing the label, we are listening for that specific notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(updateDateDisplays:) name: @"UpdatedDatesNotification" object: nil];
```

... which then passes the "formattedDates" (in this case) to the method "updateDateDisplays".

I'm sure that there are some that will tell you that this is somehow wrong but I will argue that 1) it gets the job done with minimal code 2) it's easily readable and searchable and 3) it saves a heck of a lot of time which, if you're doing this for a living, is money.